# Is there a way to increase the max zoom distance?

Tags: age-of-empires-iv

I find the camera in Age of Empires IV to be a bit too close to the battlefield for my liking. for example, in the first Normans Campaign Mission, I struggled selecting my entire army at once when it was spread across the screen. Is there a way to increase this distance?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to increase the maximum zoom distance.

It is planned to support modding sometime after release, so chances are high that a mod will be created that allows increasing the maximum zoom distance.

Apart from that, your request is a common one so there might be a chance that the developers are working on that. However, increasing the maximum zoom distance would mean more objects have to be rendered at once which would impact the hardware requirements which are unlikely to change.

Therefore I think your best bet is to wait until modding has been fully implemented.